# Sony VAIO Duo 13 Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, vaio, sony

I have the Sony VAIO Duo 13 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 Dual-Booted. I cannot get the internal wifi chip to work with Ubuntu. The internal chip works with Windows 10. I have tried many solutions including this one: [Sony Vaio Pro Duo 13 SDIO Broadcom BCM43241 Not Recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664786/sony-vaio-pro-duo-13-sdio-broadcom-bcm43241-not-recognized)

I can use a usb adapter for WIFI (not desirable) so I can download anything needed if needed for a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some more info when my usb adapter is not plugged in (internal wifi card only):

Output of

```
   $  lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
    0: nfc0: NFC
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Output of:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

Output of:

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of the following is my blacklist:

```
    # This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# Causes trackpads to stop working on Lenovo 11e 2nd gen (Ubuntu: #1802135)
# and Lenovo x240 to hang on boot (Ubuntu: #1802689)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
# blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Output of: `$ ls /lib/firmware/brcm/`

```
bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin     brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin     brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
bcm43xx-0.fw              brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw          brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
brcmfmac43143.bin         brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin     brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43236b.bin        brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4373.bin
brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin   brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin     brcmfmac-sdio.bin
brcmfmac43242a.bin        brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin     brcmfmac-sdio.txt
brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin     brcmfmac43569.bin         brcmfmac-sdio.zip
brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin
```

Lastly from pastebin

```
##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
```

From requested comment:
[Additional Drivers Screenshot - None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUfBs.png)

[output of lspici | grep Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRiOT.png)

From Windows 10 I was able to find info on the wifi adapter

> Manufacturer: Broadcom
>
> Description:  Broadcom 802.11abgn Wireless SDIO Adapter
>
> Driver version:   5.93.102.22
>
> Physical address (MAC):   (I have it but hid it for obvious reasons)

Comment: Dear Sabrina, Would you mind updating the question by placing the result of the following command `lspci | grep Network` as well? I want to know whether is a broadcom wi-fi card. Furthermore, search on dash for the keyword `drivers` and select *External Drivers* as well, then provide a screenshot of this program as well (by editing the question and placing the comment bellow to get notified).

Comment: I added some images above. They both come back with nothing, It cant find the hardware at all.

Comment: I'm confused by: `sudo echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> sudo /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` that seems to tell the kernel to ignore your laptop. Could you explain why you are doing this?

Comment: I messed up there and put the wrong code that was supposed to be the grep where I was looking for those. I replaced that in my question with the contents of my blacklist file

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the assistance. I have spent 2+ days on this and finally stumbled on the solution from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta/+bug/1777444

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Sabrina, please remember you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: I will when it lets me in 2 days :)