# Broadcom 802.11ac WDI SDIO

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a ACEPC branded compute stick like [this one (T6 Pro Stick Mini PC Pocket Computer Mini Fanless Windows 10 4Gb Ram 64Gb R T3D9)](https://www.newegg.com/p/2NR-00W5-00003?item=9SIAF279Z45944&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-topsellpo-_-all-in-one%20pcs-_-9SIAF279Z45944&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgebwBRDnARIsAE3eZjRz5SH6GCAZdDpqIYP1qpJz_2OYaIKf3wz9OqX55RHUKuR8IXQHbmcaAnoSEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). It runs Windows and the WiFi works fine.

But I cannot get this Broadcom adapter to work on Ubuntu (tried regular Ubuntu 19.10). It just doesn't see any networking hardware as present. There is no ethernet post in the PC. I have other computers which I can use to download things and bring in while the stick PC is running Ubuntu.

Any pointers will be much appreciated. In windows I see it listed as

> Broadcom 802.11ac WDI SDIO adapter

EDIT: Here are the outputs of the two commands:

dmesg | grep brcm :

```
[   31.052424] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd failed with error -2
[   31.052437] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd not found
[   31.557581] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[   31.569403] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   31.684111] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.$(DEFAULT_STRING)-$(DEFAULT_STRING).txt failed with error -2
[   31.684160] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[   34.574654] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

dmesg | grep -i sdio :

```
[   31.557581] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[   31.684111] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.$(DEFAULT_STRING)-$(DEFAULT_STRING).txt failed with error -2
[   31.684160] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[   34.574654] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Thanks for the help with editing. I also obtained the brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt from the older linked post about Sony VAIO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and the Broadcom BCM43241 card in my vaio duo 13 doesn't even show up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451920/im-running-ubuntu-14-04-and-the-broadcom-bcm43241-card-in-my-vaio-duo-13-doesn)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep brcm` terminal command.

Comment: Please dit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please format the text properly. It is unreadable. Select the text and press `{}` icon. You need to paste it again. It is hard to undo wrong formatting.

Comment: But anyway you need `brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt`

Comment: Linux firmware git doesn't have this file yet. There are some platform specific files only.

Comment: Does this mean that as of now this hardware is not supported by Ubuntu and I should consider adding a USB WiFi adapter?

Comment: It is definitely not officially supported on Ubuntu, becuase there is no firmware for it. But it is also possible to find a workaround.

Comment: Try a file from here https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/tree/master/brcm

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same pc stick and I solved the issue like this:
In the Windows partition search for the file c:\Windows\Sytem32\drivers\4345r6nvram.txt; then copy it to /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt in your Linux distro. Unload the module (rmmod brcmfmac), then load it again (modprobe brcmfmac).